# How to capture stdout and stderr in pytest fixture with session scope

Tags: python, pytest

as the caption says, I'm asking if there is any way how to capture stdout and stderr when an exception is raised in session-scoped fixture? What I get now is just a traceback, which is not really sufficient as it does not inform me about the error itself (the real info is in stderr). I tried to use capsys fixture, but it's function-scoped, so that's not the right way.
What I wish to achieve is that I'd like to 'extract' stdout and stderr when an error occurs and raise generic Error exception, which contains this output plus more information about failure.

I imagine something like this:

```
import pytest 
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session_fixture(request):
    try:
        # Critical part, which produces stdout/stderr output
    except Error as exc:
        # Extract stdout and stderr
        out, err = ...
        raise CustomError(stdout=out,
                          stderr=err,
                          ...
                          )
```

Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution using StringIO from cStringIO module.

http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/09/27/Capturing-stderr-and-exceptions-from-python-in-org-mode/